# Finding the frequency of the words in a text using struct and memory allocation

Tags: c, list, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

Given a text file, I would like to find the frequency of the words using dynamic memory allocation, however I have doubts on should I use calloc and also when to free the memory, or maybe using malloc. Could you please help me to understand my issue in this code?
Thank you so much for the consideration and feedbacks

```
struct repetition{
    char word[MAX];
    int freq;
};
```

```
int create_list(struct repetition s[], FILE *f_in) {
    int count = 0;
    char word[MAX], *lower;

    while (fscanf(f_in, "%s", word)) {
        lower = calloc(strlen(word)+1, sizeof(char));
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
            lower[i] = tolower(word[i]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            if (strcmp(s[j].word, lower) == 0) {
                s[j].freq++;
                return count;
            }
        }
        strcpy(s[count].word, lower);
        s[count].freq++;

        count++;
        free(lower);
    }
    return count  ;
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [calloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/calloc.3.html) and related functions? On what operating system are you coding? Do you use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` ? Do you use the [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) tool? Can you provide some [mre] in your question? Are you allowed to study, for inspiration, the source code of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) ? Are you allowed to use open source libraries like [Glib](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/) or study their source code?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger? Or to read the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/) ?

Comment: "find the frequency of the words using dynamic memory allocation" So can I assume that you know how to do that without memory allocation? Then please show a [mre] of that and explain what problem you want to solve by using allocation.